# use of this keyword

Tags: c#, .net, this

I am making a window form application. When I looken at the file `Form1.Designer.cs` then in the auto generated code I saw

```
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

What does **this** tells there and in how many ways this can be used in c#

Comment: In all likelihood the use of `this` here is redundant.

Comment: AFAIK, it can only be used in one way: to refer to the current instance of the class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Try to google on *this* keywrod in C#

Comment: BTW, I voted to close because any answer here will repeat information already available all over SO and all over the web. It's not a specific problem... rather it's a tuition request.

Answer (score 6):

It refers to the current instance of the class.  If you are using tools like ReSharper it can sometimes be deemed redundant.

```
public class Test
{
        private string testVariable;

        public Test(string testVariable) 
        {
            this.testVariable = testVariable;
        }
}
```

In this context `this.testVariable` refers to the private string within the class and not the `testVariable` being passed in via the constructor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dk1507sz(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4):

the ***this*** keyword refers to the current instance of a class - so in this case the instance of Form1 which is loading.

As to why you'd use it, it can help to differentiate between variables - e.g.

```
 private string bar;

 private void Foo(string bar)
 {
   this.bar = bar;
 }
```

(though for the code above, many would argue the private bar should be _bar)

For more info about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dk1507sz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The [`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/dk1507sz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword refers to the current instance of the `class` and is also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.

```
public Employee(string name, string alias)
{
// Use this to qualify the fields, name and alias:
this.name = name;
this.alias = alias;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is
>   also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.

- The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class. It can be used to access members from within constructors, instance methods, and instance accessors.
- `this` eliminates naming conflicts.
- `this` cannot refer to a static field or method. It cannot occur inside a static class.
- The `this` keyword is inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

```
  class program
{
   public int x = 10;
    public void fun1()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("as you wish");
    }
}
class program2:program
{
    public void fun2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("no");

        this.fun2(); //base class function call

        this.fun1(); // same class function call

    }
}
class program3:program2
{
   public int x = 20;
    public void fun3()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(this.x); //same class x variable call
        Console.WriteLine(base.x); // base class x variable call
       // this.fun3(); // same class function call
        Console.WriteLine("Program3 class call");
        base.fun1(); //base class function call
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        program3 pr = new program3();
        pr.fun3();
    }
```

this keyword call a current reference.if you want call a current object of the same class this keyword are used. 
How we need a this keyword???
1. Eliminate the base class and current class object.

Comment: You might want to consider trying to compile your code in your answers before you post them. This mess won't even compile (hint: You need a `new` keyword somewhere) and it is wrong on a few points in the comments.